# Avoid redirect to ADFS 2.0 signin page when accessing web site

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, wif, adfs2.0

I'm developing a MVC 3 WIF application, which exchanges claims with ADFS 2.0 and AD. It works really great, but there is one problem I can't seem to get around.

What I want to do is to keep the main page (HomeController) accessible for anonymous users, and when they enter different pages, they will be redirected to ADFS-signin. I have tried to add a location in my web.config and it works when I enter `http://localhost/Home` manually, but not when I enter `https://localhost`.

```
<location path="Home">
<system.web>
  <authorization>
    <allow users="?" />
  </authorization>
  <httpModules>
    <add name="WSFederationAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.WSFederationAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <add name="SessionAuthenticationModule" type="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Web.SessionAuthenticationModule, Microsoft.IdentityModel, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
  </httpModules>
</system.web>
```

Any suggestions on how I can work my way around this?

Comment: not too sure, but its MVC, then you should have a look at the Global.asax and see how the routing has been configured.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention that one. It routes to HomeController and Index action (default). The Index method is not flagged with [Authorize] either

Comment: could you post your `RegisterRoutes` method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the location and authorization web.config settings is strongly discouraged since it will open up security holes in your MVC application:

http://forums.asp.net/t/1583850.aspx/1/10

Instead, you should use the `[Authorize]` attribute at the controller or action level to determine which users and roles should be given access.

For your issue, if you don't have `[Authorize]` specified, the pages should allow anonymous access.